# Repeating HTML markup w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, plugins, pagination

Issue:
I'm creating a pagination plugin for a project.

Question:
What is the best way to repeat the same HTML object in jQuery?

Example:
I've set it up w/

```
function pagination(pageNumber){
    this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= pageNumber; $i ++) {
    **$('#myObject').addClass('dot');**
}}
```

I want to be able to use my for counter to iterate the object in **, I'm assuming it involves the .appendTo action, but I don't know how to tie in my variable to control the quantity.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your loop.

```
var newObject = $('#yourObject').clone()
newObject.appendTo('#targetContainer')
```

Once you've created a clone of the element you want to repeat, you just append it to your destination. You don't need to specify the number of times as an argument to either line. This will just append another element however many times the loop runs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to know how to repeat an object? Use the .clone() method http://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= pageNumber; $i ++) {
  $('.myObject').clone().addClass('dot').appendTo('.someContainer');
}
```

Remember not to duplicate element IDs.

Comment: Yeah, but when you add that feature the for counter becomes pointless. I need a way to control the amount in a static manner.

Comment: From the comments I see, at least I and maybe all of us have not understood your question. Please try to explain better, thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to be more specific. I want to be able to multiply an html object. So if I say hey, onclick I want to fire this js function with that produces x amount of an object like onClick="mulitplyDots(3)" then it will print 3 dots whether they are <img> or <div> w/ bg imgs it doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out the best way to 'print' this item like I would in php x amount of times. Do I create the element first and then create it dynamically? Do I use 'empty html buckets' as stated above? Just looking for input on the best method to execute this.

Answer (score 0):

this will sound weird, but make the html objects before you append them!! Huge performance increase

```
    var divTemplateHtml = "<div id='helloWorld' class='dot'></div>";
    var divTemplate = $(divTemplateHtml);


    function pagination(pageNumber){
    // do not add elements to an attached DOM in a for loop.
        var container = $("#container-selector").detach();
// now it's detached
        for ($i = 1; $i <= pageNumber; $i ++) {
//trust me, clone it ;)  it saves headaches on other templates
            var clone = divTemplate.clone();
//i like to use this to set IDs
            clone.attr("id", clone.attr("id") +i );
//sounds weird, but attach the fresh clone to the 'detached' container
            container.append(clone);
        }
//put the container back in the DOM
        container.appendTo("#your-final-target");
    }
```

Comment: Curious, in your example are you meaning for #container-selector & #your-final-target to be the same selector? If they are different then where are they living in the DOM? Are they being generated dynamically? Or are they serving as empty mark-up buckets that sit there just to fulfill js requests? Thanks for the input btw.

Comment: Yes, in this case they would probably be empty mark-up buckets.  When you .detach() something, there is no '.re-attach()' function to put it back in the same spot.  'Empty mark-up buckets' is one way to help with that.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I don't think this will work for what I'm trying to do. For anyone reading this thread I created my js function to make just one copy and then I multiply is server-side with php.